# Calling a PostGIS function on a set of geometries

Tags: postgis

I am trying to loop through a set of geometries and seeing if they intersect with another geometry, so something like this:

```
select unnest(
    ARRAY[
        ST_Intersects(box,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4 4)')),
        ST_Intersects(box,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4.0001 4.0001)')),
        ST_Intersects(box,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4.4 4.4)')),
        ST_Intersects(box,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4.4002 4.4002)')),
        ST_Intersects(box,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5 5)'))
    ]
) from (select ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(3,2),ST_Point(5,4)) as box) as sq
```

How can I do this without having to call ST_Intersects on each point individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you don't want to write the `st_intersects` on each one of them you can turn them around:

```
select st_intersects(st_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(3,2),ST_Point(5,4)), point) from unnest(
    ARRAY[
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4 4)'),
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4.0001 4.0001)'),
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4.4 4.4)'),
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4.4002 4.4002)'),
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5 5)')
    ]) point;
```

This way you don't repeat the intersecting, just unnest the array and check intersection to the box. Of course internally the check is always run for each of them.